# How to use a green screen to change the background color while preserving shadows?

Tags: product-photography, background, chroma-key

I want to take a picture of my chair and place it in different rooms or apply different wallpapers in the background *without* losing the shadows or the lights in the background.

First of all, do I need green screen to be able to do that?

If so, I have taken a picture with a green screen in the background. How should I place the chair in the room or apply wallpaper in the background without loosing the shadow of the chair or the lights in background?

This is the picture:

[image]

Comment: I initially thought this was a duplicate of [How to take product shots on a green screen background?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46266/how-to-take-product-shots-on-a-green-screen-background), but there's a difference — that one asks to _remove_ shadows, while this one wants to change the background while _preserving_ them. However, there's some good general advice there which still applies — such as green not necessarily being the best choice for still photography.

Comment: Also see other questions in the [tag:chroma-key] tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use many product for remove green screen. Photoshop, Gimp, PhotoKey.

But to get acceptable results you should follow few rules

1. Make the background flat, w.o. any shadows and so on
2. Use it with the foreground objects which do not have naturally green
3. Do not light (artificial or natural) the green screen or make the light on it as flat as possible
4. To apply any light on the future background picture you need lights on it, not on green screen

Comment: Your rule #1 directly contradicts what the OP is asking--how to preserve the shadows intentionally...